# Getting location updates with pending intent returns null locations

Tags: java, android, gps, android-location

Im trying to retrieve locations by passing a PendingIntent to the locationClient, but the intent I receive in the broadcast receiver has no location in it.

This is my code:

**Starting LocationRequests**

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    notifyIntent = new Intent(RunActivity.this, RunActivity.AlarmReciever.class);
    notifySender = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(RunActivity.this, 899899, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notifyIntent.setAction("com.blabla.blabla.NOTIFY_GPS");

    locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, notifySender);
}
```

**Reciever**

```
    <receiver android:name=".RunActivity$AlarmReciever"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.blabla.blabla.NOTIFY_GPS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
public static class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("RECIEVED LOCATION UPDATE", "INTENT");
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        Location loc = (Location)b.get(android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        Log.d("LOCATION", null == loc ? "emptyloc" : loc.toString());
    }
}
```

This will always print "LOCATION﹕ emptyloc".

Any ideas?

P.S.: Forgot to mention that locations are working correctly, if I call `locationClient.getLastLocation()` i will retrieve a location as expected. It is only with the PendingIntent that location is null;

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, location wasn't null, my key was wrong.

I solved this issue by getting all bundle keys, and iterating over them:

```
for (String key : b.keySet()) {
    try {
        Log.d("bundle object", b.get(key).toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```